# Math between two tables with MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my SQL database, one for the photos that users sent and another one for the votes which photo had on my application. I need to extract the 30 photos from the 'photos' table which had the most votes on the 'votes' table.

Is there a way to do it within a single query?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do this. What did you do to get to it?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a query like this:

```
select
    a.photoFileName
from
    photos a
        join votes b
            on a.photoId=b.photoId
order by 
    b.voteCount desc
limit 30
```

Adjust the keys to your exact column names on the linked fields.

This assumes that the votes table has an number column (voteCount) that has a tally of the votes for that image.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ( if each vote is stored single ), but make your own adjustments:

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  COUNT( v.id )
FROM
  photos p
JOIN
  votes v ON p.id = v.photo_id
ORDER BY
  COUNT( v.id ) DESC
GROUP BY
  v.photo_id
LIMIT 30;
```

*PS: I did not test the query, just gave you an example!*